# hibernate 4.1.7.Final with unknown table id in order by mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

i am trying to upgrade to hibernate 4.1.7.Final from 4.0.1 and i am getting the following errors:

```
Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."****/********": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."*****": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_35] 

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myatrium_intranet] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not locate table which owns column [id] referenced in order-by mapping
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.determineTableNumberForColumn(JoinedSubclassEntityPersister.java:854)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getTableAliasForColumn(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4865)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister$StandardOrderByAliasResolver.resolveTableAlias(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1930)
at org.hibernate.sql.ordering.antlr.OrderByFragmentTranslator$StandardOrderByTranslationImpl.injectAliases(OrderByFragmentTranslator.java:106)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.getSQLOrderByString(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:751)
at org.hibernate.loader.JoinWalker.orderBy(JoinWalker.java:910)
at org.hibernate.loader.JoinWalker.orderBy(JoinWalker.java:822)
at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initStatementString(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:123)
at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initStatementString(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:108)
at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initAll(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:90)
at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initAll(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:77)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.CascadeEntityJoinWalker.<init>(CascadeEntityJoinWalker.java:51)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.CascadeEntityLoader.<init>(CascadeEntityLoader.java:46)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3785)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3722)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.postInstantiate(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:1018)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:457)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
... 9 more
```

I have no clue which table hibernate is talking about. is there any way of getting to know of it? also do i need to add anything special to get it to work? mind you my datastructure was working for 4.0.1.

any help would be really appreciated.

update: i have turned on debug for hibernate, and i am wondering how to find out which class is causing the trouble. is there any way to know which class its coming from? just to remind you, the error is from pre loading queries which hibernate does before starting the server.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your *.hbx files or the entity classes with annotation please ?

Comment: thats gonna be tough, too many of them

Comment: Try to rerun your app but set hibernate level log to DEBUG or TRACE to find the table.

Comment: im in standalone.xml, not sure how to add hibernate logging to it

Comment: ok i added DEBUG, now I can see a table name before the error, but not sure if it is related to this table.

Answer (score 4):

I have figured out the scenario in which this happens finally and will be filing a bug report with hibernate soon and will link it here when I do.  If you have an entities using the Inheritance strategy of JOINED and you reference the parent entity as a collection in another entity and add an order by to the collection, the error the OP posted is thrown.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Joined_Parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class JoinedParent
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "other_entity_id", nullable = false)
    private OtherEntity otherEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Joined_Child")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class JoinedChild
    extends JoinedParent
{
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Other_Entity")
public class OtherEntity
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "otherEntity", orphanRemoval = true)
    @OrderBy("id ASC") // <-- this causes the error
    private List<JoinedParent> items = new ArrayList<JoinedParent>();
}
```

I am not sure if this only happens if you reference the parent as a collection or if it happens with the child entity as well.  I'm also not sure if having the relationship bi-directional has anything to do with it either.  I have submitted a bug report here https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7630

Comment: just tested 4.1.6, same problem...this is really painful, now 4.1.5 testing time....but they should really fix it.

Comment: in the mean time...check this out...similar problem i think : https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4394

Comment: Thanks a lot...ill keep checking it.

Comment: wow. I'm now encountering this exact problem. It works if you use 4.2.9-SNAPSHOT as in the bug is mentioned that 4.2.9 and 4.3.1 will provide a fix for this. However that's a very long time...

Comment: is this bug fixed in recent versions ? I think i still see it in 4.3.6.Final !

Comment: Thanks for saving my precious time!